# How to write test for action attribute?

Tags: unit-test

I try  to write test for my controller, my visualforce page name is PowerPlantIntroduceEdit

```
    <apex:page standardController="PowerPlantIntroduce__c" extensions="UploadPictureToCloudinaryController" action="{!initDetail}">
      some thing here ...
    </apex:page>
```

this is my controller :

```
public with sharing class UploadPictureToCloudinaryController {
    public UploadPictureToCloudinaryController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {...}
    public PageReference initDetail(){
         some logic thing ... 
    }
}
```

and this is my test class

```
@isTest
private class test_UploadPictureToCloudinaryController {
      static testmethod void testCallout() {
         PowerPlantIntroduce__c t = new PowerPlantIntroduce__c();
         Apexpages.StandardController stdController = new Apexpages.StandardController( t);
         UploadPictureToCloudinaryController controller = new UploadPictureToCloudinaryController(stdController);
         PageReference TestPage = Page.PowerPlantIntroduceEdit;
         test.setCurrentPage(TestPage);
      }
}
```

I can't pass my test to initDetail() method.

can any body help me , thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You next need to call

```
PageReference result = controller.initDetail();
```

And then test that the returned value is as expected.

Comment: thanks you . 
follow your instruction I solved my problem .